# How to solve issue with ffmpeg being stuck at 'Opening an input file'

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, alsa, audio-capture

I am using a capture card to capture HDMI audio from another machine.

On my host, output of `arecord -l` is as follow:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: capture [ezcap U3 capture], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The command that I use is:

```
sudo ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:CARD=capture,DEV=0 -t 30 test.wav -loglevel debug
```

When I ran the command, the log seems to freeze at 'Opening an input file' as below:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Splitting the commandline.

Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'alsa'.

Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'hw:CARD=capture,DEV=0'.

Reading option '-t' ... matched as option 't' (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument '30'.

Reading option 'test.wav' ... matched as output url.

Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.

Finished splitting the commandline.

Parsing a group of options: global .

Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.

Successfully parsed a group of options.

Parsing a group of options: input url hw:CARD=capture,DEV=0.

Applying option f (force format) with argument alsa.

Successfully parsed a group of options.

Opening an input file: hw:CARD=capture,DEV=0.
```

It will just stuck there forever, until I press Ctrl+C, then the log continues as follow:

```
[alsa @ 0x55c9f0eee8c0] interrupted
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'hw:CARD=capture,DEV=0':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/1000000: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url test.wav.
Applying option t (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument 30.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: test.wav.
File 'test.wav' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[file @ 0x55c9f0f03280] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Successfully opened the file.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it.
detected 4 logical cores
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x55c9f0f05dc0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x55c9f0f05dc0] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x55c9f0f05dc0] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 's16'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x55c9f0f05dc0] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x55c9f0f05dc0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:s16 samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[format_out_0_0 @ 0x55c9f0f060c0] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 's16'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55c9f0f04be0] query_formats: 5 queried, 12 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
Output #0, wav, to 'test.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/48000: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 pcm_s16le
size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (hw:CARD=capture,DEV=0):
  Input stream #0:0 (audio): 0 packets read (0 bytes); 0 frames decoded (0 samples);
  Total: 0 packets (0 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (test.wav):
  Output stream #0:0 (audio): 0 frames encoded (0 samples); 0 packets muxed (0 bytes);
  Total: 0 packets (0 bytes) muxed
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
0 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x55c9f0f033e0] Statistics: 3 seeks, 3 writeouts
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

What is wrong with the command?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I tracked it down using strace to discover that ffmpeg was unable to open the USB capture device.  Would have been nice to get an error message but it keeps trying (forever) to access the device.

Unplugged and re-plugged (i.e. reset) the capture device, now all is good.